# Cannot use import statement outside a module with Babel configured

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to use ES6 imports with Express Node.js. I know that Node.js supports CommonJS only so I have configured Babel with Webpack 4 like such:

```
{
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: ['/node_modules/', /\bcore-js\b/, /\bwebpack\/buildin\b/, /@babel\/runtime-corejs3/],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          babelrc : false,
          sourceType : "unambiguous",
          presets : [
            ["@babel/preset-env", {
              modules : false,
              useBuiltIns : "usage",
              corejs : {
                version : "2", 
              }
            }]
          ],
        }
      }
    },
```

As a test to see if it works I updated my CommonJS `require` statements into ES6 `import`s like such:

```
import express from "express"
import api from "api/v1/index.api.js"

const expressRouter = express.Router();

expressRouter.get('/', async function (req, res)  {
});

export default expressRouter
```

I believe having [read this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-es6-and-beyond-syntax-with-node-and-express-68d3e11fe1ab/) that the above should just work. But on build, I still get the following error:

> import express from "express"
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Is my `babel-loader` not working, or is there some other issue going on? Firstly not all my files are using ES6 imports - some are still using CommonJS `require` statements. I thought I'd try it on one file at a time to ensure it works which sadly it does not.

Any ideas on what to look at? I am using `core-js 2.6.11` because version `3` [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578788/core-js-3-babel-results-in-mini-css-extract-plugin-error) with `mini-css-extract-plugin`

Answer (score 1):

@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs did work for me where I needed the some commonjs lib to be used for setting up the test infrastructure. Note to add it in babel.config.js

Comment: I actually managed to solve it using @babel/node. In my package.json I run my development mode like "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js" which transpiles server.js in memory.